# Max call size reached recursing over an array

Tags: javascript

Trying to pair array values in a staggered form.

For example, after going through the function, I am looking for `new_arr` to be

```
['team1', 'team8', 'team2', 'team7', 'team3', 'team6', 'team4', 'team5']
```

Any idea why I am getting the call stack error? Am I missing a memory leak somewhere?

```
var arr = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4', 'team5', 'team6', 'team7', 'team8'];
var new_arr = [];

function staggered(arr, new_arr, min = null, max = null) {
    for (var i=0, j=arr.length-1; i < arr.length / 2; i++, j--) { 
        if(typeof min === "null") { min = i;}
        if(typeof max === "null") { max = j;}
        new_arr.push(new_arr, arr[min], arr[max]);
        return staggered(arr, new_arr, i + 1, j - 1);
    }
}

console.log(staggered(arr, new_arr));
```

Comment: `typeof null === 'object'`

Comment: just use `min === null`

Comment: How does the recursion terminate?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it doesn't, because the `for` loop always runs from `0` to `arr.length`, and yet `arr` always remains the same length

Comment: Could you provide some more details?

Answer (score 1):

Your function hits the recursion limit because the `for` loop within which the recursion happens is *always* invoked because it always runs from `0` to `arr.length / 2`, and yet `arr` always remains the same length when you recurse.

That said, there's actually no need to write this function recursively:

```
function staggered(arr) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; ) {
       res.push(arr[i++]);
       res.push(arr[--j]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Given an odd-sized input array the last pairing will team the middle entry against itself (aka a "by").

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler method with recursion without that `for` loop:

```
function staggered(arr, new_arr, i) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return new_arr;
  if (!i) arr = arr.slice(0);
  new_arr = new_arr || [];
  new_arr.push(arr.shift(), arr.pop());
  return staggered(arr, new_arr, 1);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rfpra5rp/2/)

Comment: Any user of this function should be aware that this will destroy the original array...

Comment: It's probably also trivial to write iteratively instead of recursively :p

Comment: Yeah, but I was trying to keep in the spirit of the question :)